# Stop scrolling on zoomable iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I'm working on a webpage that embeds another page from a different domain inside an iframe. The content of this page fits the iframe exactly, so there's no overflowing content and no scrollbars. However, the content can be zoomed with the mousewheel.

But in Safari and Chrome, zooming with the mousewheel also scrolls the entire page. I don't want this scrolling to happen---only the zooming of the iframe. How can I stop this scrolling when the mouse is over the iframe?

I've attempted to recreate the problem in a minimal example on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/twodee/57a68k3h. When I zoom over the green iframe, the text zooms but the page also scrolls.

```js
frame = document.getElementById('myframe');
frame_child = document.createElement('div');

var font_size = 12;
frame_child.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  font_size += e.wheelDelta;
  frame_child.style.fontSize = font_size + 'px';
});

frame_child.style.width = '190px';
frame_child.style.height = '190px';
frame_child.innerHTML = 'this text should zoom';
frame.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(frame_child);
```

```css
#myframe {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>a</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <iframe id="myframe" height="200px" width="800px" src="about:blank"></iframe>
</div>
<ul>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>
```

EDIT:
The example above is a little misleading in that the iframe source is not really generated dynamically by my own script. Instead, the source is generated by a separate website, which expects form input from the requester. Here's a CodePen that better demonstrates my issue: http://codepen.io/twodee/pen/PGqgyw. (JSFiddle only allows https:// sources.)

When I wheel over the iframe, the 3D cube zooms and the page scrolls.

EDIT:
The effect I'm after is what I see when Google Maps is embedded in a page. Or Sketchfab. When I embed these in an iframe, I don't have to do anything special in the page that's doing the embedding to make zooming happen without scrolling. There seems to be something about the embedded content itself that disables the scrolling, but I don't know what.

Comment: StackOverflow's Run Code Snippet doesn't work because of a cross-origin policy. The JSFiddle does work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have stated, preventDefault() works fine for your first example, where it's a div.

But this does not appear to be possible on iframes to external sites, because only certain events are captured on the iframe.
On this codepen, you can see that the mouseenter event is captured on the iframe, but the click and the wheel are not. 
Pay close attention to the console.log(target) statements and which work and which do not.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALXNEL?editors=1111)

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.w3schools.com">
</iframe>
<br>
<div id="div1">
  test
</div>
<div id="div2">
</div>
```

CSS

```
iframe {
  width:600px;
  height:200px;
  border: 10px solid red;
}
div {
 width:600px;
 height:40px;
 border: 10px solid blue;
}
#div2 {
 width:600px;
 height:800px;
 border: 10px solid green;
}
```

JS

```
frame = document.getElementById('myframe');
div = document.getElementById('div1');

frame.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e) {
  console.log('entered');
  var target = e.target;
  console.log(target);
});
frame.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('clicked');
  var target = e.target;
  console.log(target);
});
frame.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  console.log('wheel');
  var target = e.target;
  console.log(target);
});

font_size = 12;
div1.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  console.log(target);
  font_size += -e.wheelDelta/100;
  this.style.fontSize = font_size + 'px';

  if(target.id === 'div1')
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Updated:**
Since you say you have control over the iframe content, you can add the wheel event handler to the framed content. Try this...

HTML on the framed content

```
<div id="framedDiv">
  abc<br>
  def<br>
  ghi<br>
  jkl<br>
  mno<br>
  pqr<br>
  stu<br>
  vwx<br>
  abc<br>
  def<br>
  ghi<br>
  jkl<br>
  mno<br>
  pqr<br>
  stu<br>
  vwx<br>
  abc<br>
  def<br>
  ghi<br>
  jkl<br>
  mno<br>
  pqr<br>
  stu<br>
  vwx<br>
</div>
```

JS on the framed content

```
framed = document.getElementById('framedDiv');
font_size = 12;

framed.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  var target = e.target.id;
  console.log(target);
  font_size += -e.wheelDelta/100;
  this.style.fontSize = font_size + 'px';
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Somehow sites like SketchFab make it so that zooming doesn't propagate up to the parent frame and lead to scrolling. There's something about the iframe content that influences this. I have control over the iframe content, but I don't know what properties to tweak. In your CodePen, the parent frame starts scroll once I've reached the bottom of the iframe content. For my content, I essentially have no bottom (or top), and I never want the scrolling to happen.

Comment: I have updated my answer since you say you have control over the frame content - add the wheel event to the framed content page.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like I would have had my answer days ago if I had just realized the wheel listener needed to be part of the iframe content.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>You can add mouse event listeners on your Iframe to check to see if your mouse is in it, and if it is then stop the scroll from happening on the window:</strike>

```
frame = document.getElementById('myframe');
frame_child = document.createElement('div');
var font_size = 12;
var inFrame=false;
frame_child.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
  font_size += e.wheelDelta;
  frame_child.style.fontSize = font_size + 'px';
});
frame.addEventListener("mouseover",function(e){
inFrame=true;
});
frame.addEventListener("mouseout",function(e){
inFrame=false;
});
window.addEventListener('wheel',function(e){
if(inFrame)
    e.preventDefault();
})
frame_child.style.width = '190px';
frame_child.style.height = '190px';
frame_child.innerHTML = 'this text should zoom';
frame.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(frame_child);
```

Just add prevent default on your div wheel listener:

```
frame_child.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
  font_size += e.wheelDelta;
  frame_child.style.fontSize = font_size + 'px';
});
```

Comment: What if the iframe content wasn't so conveniently generated like in the example? I've added a code snippet that more faithfully demonstrates my problem.

Comment: This ended up being the answer, but the code needs to be part of the embedded iframe content itself, not part of the embedding context.

Answer (score 2):

use this code on mouse `:hover`

```
    $("#myframe").hover(
  function() {
   function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
  }, function() {
     if (window.removeEventListener)
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
    window.onwheel = null; 
    window.ontouchmove = null;  
    document.onkeydown = null;  
  }
);

$( "#myframe.fade" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).fadeOut( 100 );
  $( this ).fadeIn( 500 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a listener for window (the iframe's parent) and try this:

```
window.addEventListener("wheel", function () {

    if ($("#myframe").is(":hover")) {

        // call iframe zoom function here

        return false;

    }

});
```

When the mouse is hovering over the iframe, return false on the window scroll but execute the zoom.

Comment: I tried this, but while I do indeed get callsbacks while hovering over elements in the parent, I get none when I wheel over the iframe. This makes me feel like it's got to be some property of the iframe itself or its content.